# JavaFX WebView doesn't load content

Tags: java, javafx, webview, javafx-webengine

I'm trying to load a Google Maps page inside my JavaFX application using webView and webEngine. Somehow, it doesn't load anything and I don't know why.
Could you please help?

```
@FXML WebView webView;
WebEngine webEngine;
webView = new WebView();
webEngine = webView.getEngine();
webEngine.load("https://maps.google.de");
```

Comment: Try removing `webView = new WebView();`.  You’re creating a new WebView that is replacing the one defined in your FXML file and therefore is not a part of your Stage (probably).

Comment: Thank you! :) That's the solution.

Comment: Could you move the answer to the answers section and mark thread as solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@FXML WebView webView;
WebEngine webEngine;
webEngine = webView.getEngine();
webEngine.load("https://maps.google.de");
```

Removing webView = new WebView(); fixed it!